# Angular: children route not detected

Tags: angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, angular6, angular2-router

This is my dashboard.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {JwtModule} from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import {AuthService} from '../services/auth.service';

import {dashboardComponent} from './dashboard.component';
import { foodPollComponent } from '../modules/foodPoll/foodPoll.component';
import { dashboardModuleRoutingModule } from './dashboard.routing.module';

@NgModule({
imports: [
CommonModule, dashboardModuleRoutingModule
],
declarations: [
dashboardComponent,
foodPollComponent
],
providers: [JwtModule, AuthService]
})
export class dashboardModule { }
```

This is my dashboard.routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }     from '@angular/core';
import { Routes,
RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { dashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { foodPollComponent } from '../modules/foodPoll/foodPoll.component';

const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'dashboard',
    component:dashboardComponent
},
{
    path: 'dashboard/:id',
    component: dashboardComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'foodPoll',
            component: foodPollComponent,
            outlet: "details"
        }
    ]
}
];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class dashboardModuleRoutingModule {}
```

This is my dashboard.component.html

```
<div class="dashboard">
 <header>Random header text</header>
 <router-outlet name="details"></router-outler>
</div>
```

But when I change from **localhost:4200/dashboard** to **localhost:4200/dashboard/foodPoll**, nothing renders in the router outlet view. The view still remains the same as dashboard page.

Where I am doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
path: 'dashboard/:id',
component: dashboardComponent,
children: [
    {
        path: 'foodPoll',
        component: foodPollComponent,
        outlet: "details"
    }
]
```

`dashboardComponent` would be on url: `"dashboard/...anything.../"`

`foodPollComponent` would be on url: `"dashboard/...anything.../foodPoll"`

`:id` - is dynamic parameter for `dashboardComponent`